# Hundred year date conversion in ssis derived column

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to convert a Hundred Year Date (HYD) format to a regular date format through SSIS derived column transform.  For example:  Convert 41429
 to 06/04/2013.  I can do it with formatinng code within a script (and maybe I simply have to go this route) but feel there has to be a way to do so within a derived column that I'm just not getting.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to clarify what HYD format actually is, or at least link to a useful site. Googling doesn't (immediately) show any clear definition of what it is. And if you have working code to do it, it would be useful to see that too.

Comment: HYD starts at 1/1/1900 and is the number of days that have transpired from 1/1/1900 to whatever date of your choosing (or that a system spits out). So HYD for 12/31/1900 = 366 (must have been a leap year), HYD for 1/1/1910 = 3654 (roughly 10 years * 365 plus a few days for leap year), and HYD for 6/4/2013 = 41429. Unfortunately the system that we query from has the date in this HYD format. Within a script the simple answer is this line of code: Format(DateTime.FromOADate(Row.Date2), "MM/dd/yyyy"). I try to refrain from scripts when not necessary but it just might be.

Comment: 1900 was [not a leap year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) so the actual start date might be 1899-21-31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with. Are you sure your conversion is correct? My answer is 1 day.  off.

```
DECLARE @t1 as date = '01/01/1900';
DECLARE @t2 as DATE = '12/31/1900';
DECLARE @hyd as INT;
```

-- This example shows that we need to add 1
    SELECT @hyd = DATEDIFF (d, @t1, @t2) + 1 -- 364 + 1
    SELECT @hyd

```
set @t2 = '06/04/2013';
SELECT @hyd = DATEDIFF (d,@t1, '06/04/2013') + 1-- 41427
SELECT @hyd
SELECT DATEADD (d, @hyd, '01-JAN-1900')

SELECT DATEADD (d, 41429, '01-JAN-1900')
```

Comment: Yes this is the answer I was looking for.  I don't know why I didn't think of that.  Thankyou.  Yeah I actually got those figures from converting a date on an excel spreadsheet to a number format.  I think it is off by one - it was more for illustrating the general idea of the HYD.

Answer (score 0):

A hundred year date is a calculation based on the number of days since 1899-12-31. It's an "Excel Thing". It also has a [bug](http://www.debugging.com/bug/19252) in it that you must account for.

The equivalent TSQL logic would be

```
DECLARE
    @HYD int = 41429;

SELECT
    @HYD = 
    CASE 
        WHEN @HYD > 60
            THEN @HYD -1
        ELSE
            @HYD      
    END;

SELECT
    DATEADD(d, @HYD, '1899-12-31') AS HYD;
```

Armed with that formula, I can write the following Expression in a Derived Column Transformation (assuming you have a column named `HYD`)

```
(HYD > 60) ? DATEADD("d",HYD - 1,(DT_DATE)"1899-12-31") : DATEADD("d",HYD,(DT_DATE)"1899-12-31")
```

[image]

And the results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```sql
--or inline SQL...using this

SELECT 
case when ([HYD] > 60) then 
  DATEADD(day,[HYD] - 1,'1899-12-31') 
else    
  DATEADD(day,[HYD],'1899-12-31') 
end 'HYD_conv'
FROM 
  TableName

--and in the where clause if you like...

WHERE 
  (case when ([HYD] > 60) then DATEADD(day,[HYD] - 1,'1899-12-31') else     DATEADD(day,[HYD],'1899-12-31') end)  =  '2016-01-14'
```